# Помогите найти общую сумму корзины при нажате плюс минус

Tags: javascript, php

как взять количество и получить окончательную сумму при клике изменить общую сумму

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function change($tr, val) {
    var $input = $tr.find('.quantity');
    var count = parseInt($input.val()) + val;
    count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
    $input.val(count);
    var $price = $tr.find('.count_price');
    $price.text(count * $price.data('price'));
  }
  $('.minus').click(function() {
    change($(this).closest('tr'), -1);
  });
  $('.plus').click(function() {
    change($(this).closest('tr'), 1);
  });
 
  $('.quantity').on("input", function() {
    var $price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.count_price');
    $price.text(this.value * $price.data('price'));
   
  });

});
```

```html
<main>
<table class="shopping_list">
<tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Action</th>
</tr>

<?php 

  $total = 0;  

    include "basket/connect.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `basket` ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 

?>
 <tr>
  <td><img src=img/<?php echo $row['image_url'];?>> </td>
  <td><?php echo $row['name'];?>  </td>
  <td>$ <?php echo $row["price"];?></td>
  <td>
<button class="minus" type="button" style="width:17%;">
<i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
<input class="quantity" type="text" value='<?php echo $row["quantity"]; ?>' style="width:17%;"/>
<button class="plus" type="button" style="width:17%;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
</td>
  
 <td><span class="count_price" data-price="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>">$ <?php echo $row["price"]; ?>  </span></td>

  <td> <form method="POST" action='basket/delete.php ?id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?> '>
       <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Remove">
  </form></td>
<?php

$total = $total +  ($row["quantity"] * $row["price"]);
?>
</tr>
<?php
}
  }

 ?>
 <tr>
<td colspan="4" align="right">Total</td>
<td class="n"> $ <?php echo number_format($total,2); ?></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>


<div class="Pay for the order">
<a class="a1" href="login.php"><input type="submit" name="add_to_online-shopping"class="btn btn-success" value="Pay for the order" style="margin: 4% 0% 3% 44%;"/></a>
</div> 

    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script-3.js"></script>

</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Писал на скорую руку, так что извините, могут быть ошибки. Но думаю доточите.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function recalcTotalSumm() {
    let totalSumm = 0;
    $('table.shopping_list tr td .count_price').each( function(){
        totalSumm += parseFloat( $(this).text() );
    });
    $('table.shopping_list tr td.n').html(' $ '+parseFloat(totalSumm).toFixed(2)); //ВНИМАНИЕ! Могут быть ошибки `округления`
  }

  function change($tr, val) {
    //У переданного <tr> ищем <input type=text> с классом `quantity`
    var $input = $tr.find('.quantity');
    //Берем из него значение (а где проверка что мы его нашли? а вдруг $input у нас undefined?)
    var count = parseInt($input.val()) + val;
    //Проверяем, что если кол-во не меньше 1 (так как мы эту функцию вызываем и для увеличения так и для уменьшения кол-ва) 
    count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
    //Меняем значение <input type=text> с классом `quantity` на новое
    $input.val(count);
    //У переданного <tr> ищем элемент с классом `.count_price` 
    var $price = $tr.find('.count_price');
    //Берем из него значение его атрибута `data-price` (а где проверка что мы его нашли? а вдруг $price у нас undefined?)
    //И где приведение к типу float? У нас же цена может быть - руб.коп
    //И пересчитываем итоговую сумму за указанное кол-во товаров
    $price.text(count * $price.data('price'));
    //я бы сделал так
    //$price.text( parseFloat( count * parseFloat( $price.data('price') ) );

    //Меняем итоговую цену за всю корзину
    recalcTotalSumm();
  }

  //При клике на кнопку "Уменьшить кол-во" вызываем функцию `change`
  $('.minus').click(function() {
    //Так как кнопка у нас находится внутри <tr> то при нажатии на нее ищем у нее ближайший <tr>
    //я бы искал `parent`
    change($(this).closest('tr'), -1);
  });

  //При клике на кнопку "Увеличить кол-во" вызываем функцию `change`
  $('.plus').click(function() {
    //Так как кнопка у нас находится внутри <tr> то при нажатии на нее ищем у нее ближайший <tr>
    //я бы искал `parent`
    change($(this).closest('tr'), 1);
  });

  //Почему на `input`? Может все же на `blur` (т.е когда покупатель ввел кол-во и убрал курсор из поля ввода, либо на `onchange`) ?
  $('.quantity').on("input", function() {
    //Где проверки что `this/value` не отрицательное и целое? А если Вам введут `-1`, `0.0002`?
    var $price = $(this).closest('tr').find('.count_price');
    $price.text(this.value * $price.data('price'));
    //Меняем итоговую цену за всю корзину
    recalcTotalSumm();
   
  });

});
```